# submit of ExecutorService confusion in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

Here is the method I am referring to, and wondering if I call submit, without using Future's get method to retrieve the result, whether there will be any thread leak (I mean a thread in thread pool never be able to be reused again since its result is not retrieved), which will impact the performance of the whole thread pool in the future? Thanks.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit-java.util.concurrent.Callable-

regards,
Lin

Comment: _I mean a thread in thread pool never be able to be reused again since its result is not retrieved_ Can you describe the behavior you're thinking of here?

Comment: That's something you could easily test:  Create a fixed thread pool, submit more requests than the number of threads, and see what happens.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, thanks for the reply and vote up. I suppose if thread pool is of size 5, if I submit 5 threads, without retrieving the result, whether I can submit the 6th thread? This is the question.

Comment: You don't submit threads, you submit `Runnable` or `Callable` instances. Results aren't stored in threads, they're stored in objects. Why do you expect an object to prevent a thread from running?

Comment: @jameslarge, I did simple testing and do not see any issues, but I am not fully confident since I think the best way is to find something on java doc to see its behavior, but I cannot find from the page I posted. So, it is why I come here. Vote up for your reply for testing ideas.

Comment: I am a big fan of "learning tests."  If I'm writing code that depends on a third party library, and I'm unsure how the library will behave under certain circumstances, I write a unit test for it, just as if it was my own code.  I _keep_ the unit test as a permanent part of the project, because it documents the assumptions that I am making about the library, and because it will alert me if I switch to a newer version of the library that no longer conforms to my previous expectations.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, got it and vote up for the reply, so it should not be any impact on thread pool worker thread. But it may impact the performance of memory? i.e. if I do not retrieve result, memory will be larger and larger and may trigger GC, correct?

BTW, your comments are more clear than Java doc. LOL. :)

Comment: @jameslarge, vote up. If you could come back to the original question, it will be great. :)

Comment: It is difficult to think of and document all the things a library doesn't do. It doesn't have a problem the designers probably never thought of.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, thanks and vote up. But I do not see such internals are explicitly mentioned in java doc. It should be an FAQ for executor service. :)

Comment: You can only say what it does, not the bugs it doesn't have because then you would have to include every bad idea which they avoided by not having them in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you need to know is that `ExecutorService` is an interface, not a class, so the answer *could* be different for different implementations of `ExecutorService`.

That being said, It wouldn't make sense for most applications if an `ExecutorService` behaved in the way that you're worried about.  It would make much more sense if each worker thread would store its result in the `Future` object that was returned to the client, and then forget about the result, and forget about the `Future`, and move on to the next task.

*IF* that's how it is implemented, and *if* your code also forgot about the `Future`, then the `Future` and the result both would be collected by the GC, and that would be the end of it.

That's the implementation that would make sense to me.  You can see for yourself how the `ThreadPoolExecutor` class in the OpenJDK project actually does it by examining the source code:

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent

I took a quick peek, but I don't have time to study it in-depth.

As I said in my comment (above), I would write a test, and find out for myself if I had any doubt.

Comment: Thanks James, vote up for the reply. Wondering if any impact the performance of memory? i.e. if I do not retrieve result, memory will be larger and larger and may trigger GC, correct?

Comment: @LinMa, Ignoring a result that has aready been returned by your task will not increase memory usage.  The memory was allocated when your task created the object, and it will be reclaimed by the GC soon after the object becomes "unreachable." (i.e., When there are no variables in the program that refer to it.)

Comment: Thanks James, vote up and mark your reply as answer. Appreciate for the patience to explain to me.